# Реализация отзыва, передача из input по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, функции, input, button, try-catch

По заданию необходимо было:
Создать HTML-структуру с полем для ввода отзыва и кнопкой для отправки, где будут отображаться введенные отзывы.
Реализовать ф-ю кот. добавляет отзыв в контейнер с отзывами (в моем случае id="pattern").
Должны быть ограничения на ввод символов не менее 50 и не более 500 и генерировать исключения.
Так-же отзыв должен отображаться под предыдущим отзывом.

Подскажите, как сделать отображение введенного текста через input друг за другом

```js
feedback.addEventListener('click', () => {
  try {
    const userInp = userInput.value;
    if (userInp.trim() === '') {
      error.textContent = 'Вы ничего не ввели, прежде чем отправить отзыв!';
      throw new Error('Пустой текст');
    } else if (userInp.length > 500 || userInp.length < 50) {
      error.textContent = 'Текст не должен быть больше 500 и меньше 50 символов';
      throw new Error('Больше 500 символов');
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Введите отзыв">
  <button id="feedback" type="button">Отправить отзыв</button>
  <div id="error"></div>
  <div id="pattern"></div>
</div>
```

---

Попробовал реализовать

```
pattern.textContent = userInp
```

Но текст заменяет предыдущий(

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Отзывы, наверное, надо где то хранить? В базе например и отображать их на странице. Просто добавить текст из инпута на страницу - забудется при перезагрузке страницы. Если просто надо на странице отобразить то `контейнер.appendChild(<ВАШ_HTML_ЭЛЕМЕНТ_С_ТЕКСТОМ_ИЗ_INPUT>)`

Comment: контейнер.appendChild(<ВАШ_HTML_ЭЛЕМЕНТ_С_ТЕКСТОМ_ИЗ_INPUT>) если не ошибаюсь, то он тогда просто будет заменять текст, а не добавлять ниже новый

Comment: [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) добавляет дочерний элемент, просто [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/append) добавляет элемент рядом